# What should be done in case of some old PLC's on which OPC server is not running, can we make connection to them without using any third party tools?

Tags: opc-ua, opc

I am using open62541 C library.

Need to check connection and read parameters with PLC's of SIMATIC controllers, Allen Bradley PLCs and Programmable Controllers MELSEC in case there in no OPC-UA server running on it.

What approach should I follow to avoid any third party tool ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid third party tools then you need to develop implementations of the native protocol for each of the PLCs you need to communicate with.

Good luck. This is why products like Kepware exist instead.